# How to merge values into similar key

Tags: php

I am looking for a function, if any, to preserve or merge values into similar key, but no luck so far.

[array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) simply removes the value:

```
array_combine(array('a','a','b'), array(1,2,3));
```

**Returns:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [b] => 3
)
```

**Expected:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1,2
    [b] => 3
)
```

Any hint is very much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE: I didn't know, and didn't articulate better about the merged values (1,2), but then I had better accepted Jeroen array of values for easier breakdowns of possible array of values. 
Thanks to everyone who has kindly helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
function array_combine_custom($arr1, $arr2) {
    $out = array();

    $arr1 = array_values($arr1);
    $arr2 = array_values($arr2);

    foreach($arr1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        $out[(string)$value1] [] = $arr2[$key1];
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Spent 2 hours searching before giving up with a question. You made my day. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $v) {
  $out[$v] .= (strlen($out[$v]) ? ',' : '').array_shift($arr2);
}
```

`$out` now:

```
Array
(
  [a] => 1,2
  [b] => 3
)
```

Comment: This is almost expected answer except that I got: Notice: Undefined index. And on second thought, I should go with array for easier breakdowns of possible array of values. Sorry for not clear question. Thanks a lot.